# update array of object using javascript es6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

is there any other way to write update an item in array of object other than below code?

```
const updateTodo = (list, updated) => {
   const index = list.findIndex(item => item.id === update.id)
   return [
   ...list.slice(0,index),
   updated,
   ...list.slice(index+1)
   ]
}
```

Wait, is above function even working? https://jsbin.com/sifihocija/2/edit?js,console

Answer (score 1):

The way you are doing it, is the right way to do it. However it is not working for you because in your case `updated` is an array and not an object and hence you only need to access the `id` of the first element of the array

```
const updateTodo = (list, updated) => {

   const index = list.findIndex(item => return item.id === updated[0].id)

   return [
   ...list.slice(0,index),
   updated[0],
   ...list.slice(index+1)
   ]
}
```

**[JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/cenocozija/1/edit?js,console)**

However I prefer the library `immutability-helper` to perform any updates on the data you can do that like

```
import update from 'immutability-helper';
const updateTodo = (list, updated) => {
const index = list.findIndex(item => return item.id === updated[0].id)
   return update(list, {
        [index]: {
              $set: updated[0];
        }

   })
}
```

One advantage of using `immutabilty-helper` is that its gives more control when the data is highly nested

Answer (score 0):

You are doing to much. No need to manipulate the array if you know the index.

```
const items = [{id: 1, value: 1}, {id: 2, value: 2}, {id: 3, value: 3}];
items[2] = {id: 4, value: 4};
console.log(items); //last element changed
```

if you care about no side effects copy the array before

```
const items = [{id: 1, value: 1}, {id: 2, value: 2}, {id: 3, value: 3}];
const copy = items.slice();
copy[2] = {id: 4, value: 4};
return copy;
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to update(addition/deletion) an array is to use splice method.

it takes the first argument as the index, second as the no of elements you want to remove and next arguments for the addition.